# Overlaying xsavebox with qrcode

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, boxes

As a continuation of the question [Producing a document with a lot of almost identical pages in the most efficient way](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415405/producing-a-document-with-a-lot-of-almost-identical-pages-in-the-most-efficient) I am trying to overlay my `xsavebox` with a `qrcode`. However, something fails: qrcode and the contents of the box appear on different pages, while I want QR to be in the right corner.

**Note:** the QR code will be different for each page, but the contents of the box will not change.

A LuaLaTeX MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[showframe,margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{xsavebox}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{qrcode}

\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}


\newcommand{\Hello}{
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | X | p{6cm} | }
        \begin{minipage}[t][6cm][c]{\linewidth}
            \sffamily\bfseries\LARGE\centering Header
        \end{minipage}
        &
        {}
    \end{tabularx}

    \vspace*{2cm}

    \lipsum[1-4]
}

\xsavebox{MyBox}{
    \begin{minipage}[t][\textheight]{\textwidth}
        \Hello
    \end{minipage}
}

    \foreach\AA in{1,...,100}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[shift={(-3cm-0.5in,-3cm-0.5in)}] at (current page.north east) {
                \qrcode[height=6cm,level=H]{123456789};
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \xusebox{MyBox}

    \newpage
    }

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: It also works if you remove the empty lines of your original code. (I also replace `\newpage` by `\clearpage`, but this is not important here.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[showframe,margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{xsavebox}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{qrcode}

\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\Hello}{
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | X | p{6cm} | }
        \begin{minipage}[t][6cm][c]{\linewidth}
            \sffamily\bfseries\LARGE\centering Header
        \end{minipage}
        &
        {}
    \end{tabularx}

    \vspace*{2cm}

    \lipsum[1-4]
}

\xsavebox{MyBox}{%
\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight]{\textwidth}
        \Hello
\end{minipage}
}

    \foreach\AA in{1,...,100}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[shift={(-3cm-0.5in,-3cm-0.5in)}] at (current page.north east) {
                \qrcode[height=6cm,level=H]{\AA}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
%
    \xusebox{MyBox}
%
    \clearpage
    }

\end{document}
```

**Artefacts** ... also works.
`eso-pic` does overlay every page with the same thing, whether or not this is the most efficient way I don't know. **UPDATE**: This example uses the qrcode of `\AA`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[showframe,margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{xsavebox}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{qrcode}

\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\begin{document}


\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[shift={(-3cm-0.5in,-3cm-0.5in)}] at (current page.north east) {
         \qrcode[height=6cm,level=H]{\AA};      
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}}



\newcommand{\Hello}{
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | X | p{6cm} | }
        \begin{minipage}[t][6cm][c]{\linewidth}
            \sffamily\bfseries\LARGE\centering Header
        \end{minipage}
        &
        {}
    \end{tabularx}

    \vspace*{2cm}

    \lipsum[1-4]
}

\xsavebox{MyBox}{
    \begin{minipage}[t][\textheight]{\textwidth}
        \Hello
    \end{minipage}
}

    \foreach\AA in{1,...,100}{


    \xusebox{MyBox}

    \newpage
    }

\end{document}
```

Comment: The qrcode will be different, only the contents of the box will be the same

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman I see. Do you have an example that illustrates how the qrcode depends on `\AA`?

Comment: It will be calculated with a complex algorithm inside a luacode environment. But we can use just \qrcode{\AA}, for example.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman OK, done.

Comment: I will test it get to my pc.

Comment: It works, thx! But you should remove `;` from `\qrcode[height=6cm,level=H]{\AA};` and change `\xsavebox{MyBox}{
    \begin{minipage}[t][\textheight]{\textwidth}
        \Hello
    \end{minipage}
}` to `\xsavebox{MyBox}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t][\textheight]{\textwidth}
        \Hello
    \end{minipage}
}`